# Horizontal scrollbar on browsers suggests white space to the right, how to fix?

Tags: html, css

When my website is scaled down and a horizontal scroll bar apears, a white space is suggested on the right side of my webpage at the footer.

How am I able to fix this? url: http://www.deserved.nl/shop/home.html

Comment: I don't see any horizontal scrollbars...

Comment: @Truth it shows at 75% zoom only that I see.

Comment: @Truth IE8 (at work, no other choice)

Comment: @Truth I don't think Mittchel means 'scaled down'. If you resize your browser to smaller than his page width, the footer cuts off on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jeff B: Please let me know if it's inappropriate to add this as a separate answer rather than as a comment to your answer.

Jeff is correct, but to clarify I would do this:

1. Remove the `padding-left: 180px;` style from class `.footerWrapper`
2. Remove `width: 100%;` from `#footer`
3. Add `min-width: 1141px;` to `#footer`

This should take care of the white-space.

Comment: No, I think it's fine to add your answer here, as it gives actual information to fix the problem.  I was testing a similar solution, but yours is a bit simpler than mine.

Comment: OT: If you aren't concerned about rep, you should edit Jeff's answer

Comment: Ah ty @RyanB I didn't know you could edit someone's answer o_o and I had to google OT :D I am trying to build a little rep atm if that's alright. If not, I will gladly edit Jeff's. OT question: what happens when a user edit's an answer and screws it all up?

Comment: Thanks Jeff and Tracy! appreciate it ;)

Comment: @TracyFu you should be able to see the edit link, I think your rep is high enough. The original person and mods can revert/reject edits - if the other person (you in this case) messes it up.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are defining the width of `wrapper` to be `1141px`, and `footer` to be `100%`.  This means that when the width is less than 1141px, you will have a horizontal scroll bar, but your footer will still be 100% of the window size, resulting in white space on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the whitespace between the footer's end tag `</div>` and `</body>`

So like this: `</div></body>`