# Horizontal scrollbar and white space on right side on a web page

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i have created this web page and now somehow it has a white space about 10 pixels on right side which **causes horizontal scroll bar to show up.**
Now i have checked the markup and divs are fully closed.
The page is complex with lots of code.
can you suggest what can i do to remove this problem?
thanks.

Comment: where is your webpage?

Comment: the work is in progress so i cant upload it right now.

Comment: Can you include any styles that involve the html or body in your question please?

Comment: use inspect element..

Comment: did you used CSS reset for your webpage?

Comment: If you can't upload it to look at, the best thing to do (and what you should arguably be doing all the time) is to cut out the code what works until there's only the code left which is causing the problem.

Comment: used the firebug tool. in inspect element with firebug find layout tab  is show diagram to margin,padding,etc show all check.

Comment: @renishkhunt Ok i will try to upload as soon as Possible.

Comment: First prepare your webpage code then upload ... or else your question will be closed in just few minutes.

Comment: also i recommended to used normalize.css download here http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontal scrollbar on browsers suggests white space to the right, how to fix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212740/horizontal-scrollbar-on-browsers-suggests-white-space-to-the-right-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible reasons for this, the most common is the default margin and padding values of several elements, specially the `<body>` element. You may want to try a CSS reset on it:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

And since you don't provide a code sample, maybe you would also want to reset the following common elements that feature default margin and padding values:

```css
p, h1, h2, h3, …, li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```